# 'v-bind' directives require an attribute value - with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create some dynamic classes like so:

```
<div :class="{ 'chunk-' + chunk.length : true, 'is-mobile' : isGridView }" class="columns">
```

But I am getting error:

```
'v-bind' directives require an attribute value.
```

If I do it like so, I don't get the error:

```
<div :class="{ 'chunk-' : true, 'is-mobile' : isGridView }" class="columns">
```

But I do need the `chunk.length` value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this issue by adding the dynamic class like:

```
<div :class="{ ['chunk-' + chunk.length] : true, ['is-mobile'] : isGridView }">
```

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data: {
    chunk: [1, 2],
    isGridView: true
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

```css
.chunk-2 {
  background-color:skyblue;padding: 20px; margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="myApp">
  <div :class="{ ['chunk-' + chunk.length] : true, 'is-mobile' : isGridView }" class="columns">
    Dynamic Classes in Vue
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That definitely let's me save my file without errors - can't believe it's not documented , however, now I get a very strange error, I haven't seen before: `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:132)                              friendly-errors 13:24:20
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.`

Comment: If I do it like so: `:class="{ ['chunk-' + chunk.length] : true }"` then it works. It also works if I do ` :class="{ 'is-mobile' : isGridView }"` but not if I do ` :class="{ ['chunk-' + chunk.length] : true, 'is-mobile' : isGridView }"`

Comment: Strangely, this works: `:class="{ ['chunk-' + chunk.length] : true, ['is-mobile'] : isGridView }"`

Comment: That's strange. I have never come across such an issue. Maybe you can use what is working for now.

Comment: Maybe vue loader is not able to parse the class object having mixed key formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the other way round to use ternary operators to add classes to your element as

```
<div :class="[true ? 'chunk-' + chunk.length :'', isGridView ? 'is-mobile' : '']">
```

Though it is a few characters more, you will definitely stay away from the unpredictable compiler behavior.